# PHP not updating correctly on POST

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a function that will allow a user to enter a name into a field, insert the field to a MySQL table and then update a dropdown menu to include those names (while allowing for further additions).

On first load of the page, the dropdown menu shows the correct names that I seeded into the table. When I input a name into the form, it inserts to the table correctly, but then none of the options show in the dropdown list and it removes my entry form. If I refresh the page, everything comes back fine, and the names previously entered show up in the list.

I know I'm missing something obvious in the code to refresh the page, but I'm not even sure what to search for. I thought that by setting my form action to .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. it would cause the page to process and reload. I have a hunch this is where my problem is, but I'm not sure what it is.

The dropdown code was something I found off the web, perhaps I have to rewrite it myself, though it's the one part of this mess that's actually working.

Also, the mysql login is hardcoded in db_tools.php b/c I can't get it to work otherwise.

Sorry for the following wall of text, but I'm just trying to provide the most information possible. Thank you for your replies and pointing me in the right direction.

I have 2 files, db_tools.php and dropdown.inc

db_tools.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'db_login.php';
require_once 'MDB2.php'; 
require_once("dropdown.inc");


//Define a function to perform the database insert and display the names
function insert_db($name){

//initialize db connection
//$dsn = 'mysql://$db_username:$db_password@$db_hostname/$db_database';
$dsn = "mysql://redacted";
$mdb2 =& MDB2::connect($dsn);
if (PEAR::isError($mdb2)) {
//die($mdb2->getMessage());
die($mdb2->getDebugInfo());

}

//Manipulation query
$sql = " INSERT INTO participants (id, name) VALUES (NULL, \"$name\");";
$affected =& $mdb2->exec($sql);
if (PEAR::isError($affected)){
//die($affected->getMessage());
die($affected->getDebugInfo());
}    

//Display query
$query = "SELECT * FROM participants;";
$result =& $mdb2->query($query);
if (PEAR::isError($result)){
die ($result->getMessage());
}

while ($row = $result->fetchRow()){
echo $row[1] . "\n";
}
$mdb2->disconnect();
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Event Bill Splitter</title>
<body>
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
if ($name != NULL){
insert_db($name);
}

else {
echo '
<h1>Enter a new participant</h1>
<form name="nameForm" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="POST">
Name:<input name="name" type="text" />
</form>';
}
?>

<p>Participants:<br />
<?php dropdown(id, name, participants, name, participant_name1); ?></p>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

dropdown.inc

```
require_once ('db_login.php');

$connection = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password);

if (!$connection) {
die ("Could not connect to the database: <br />". mysql_error() );
}

$db_select = mysql_select_db($db_database);
if (!$db_select) {
die ("Could not select the database: <br />". mysql_error() );
}

function dropdown($intNameID, $strNameField, $strTableName, $strOrderField, $strNameOrdinal, $strMethod="asc") {

//
// PHP DYNAMIC DROP-DOWN BOX - HTML SELECT
//
// 2006-05, 2008-09, 2009-04 http://kimbriggs.com/computers/

echo "<select name=\"$strNameOrdinal\">\n";
echo "<option value=\"NULL\">Select Value</option>\n";

$strQuery = "select $intNameID, $strNameField
           from $strTableName
           order by $strOrderField $strMethod";

$rsrcResult = mysql_query($strQuery);

while($arrayRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsrcResult)) {
  $strA = $arrayRow["$intNameID"];
  $strB = $arrayRow["$strNameField"];
  echo "<option value=\"$strA\">$strB</option>\n";
}

echo "</select>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Just debug your code checking if the intermediate variables contain expected data for **each line**

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the form disappearing is simple, just remove the `else` after the insert section:

```
<body>
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
if ($name != NULL){
insert_db($name);
}

// else {               // gone
echo '
<h1>Enter a new participant</h1>
<form name="nameForm" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="POST">
Name:<input name="name" type="text" />
</form>';
// }                    // gone
?>
```

Apart from that I would definitely re-write the dropdown code and add some security, a whitelist for table names, etc.

By the way, you are calling your function in a strange way:

```
<?php dropdown(id, name, participants, name, participant_name1); ?>
```

I assume these are variables so it should be `$id` etc, but where do they come from? If you mean to send values directly, it should be:

```
<?php dropdown('id', 'name', 'participants', 'name', 'participant_name1'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at rewriting the dropdown code; I'm trying to get the functionality working before "bells and whistles", luckily this is just a personal learning project and contains no personal data.

I was calling the function like that because that's how the function author gave the example. They are getting sent directly; I will add the proper syntax. I am coming to PHP from C#, so things are still a little weird and I'm amazed when things work at all.

Comment: @user1139680 If you are just starting, I would go directly to PDO for all database interaction: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php